# Согласование числа при перечислении

Tags: согласование

Здравствуйте.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в следующем вопросе.
Как следует согласовывать число при перечислении?

Вот, например, предложение:

> Мальчишки зарычали во все горло, пытаясь этим криком разогнать
>   **сгущающуюся** тьму, страх и зловоние.

Вполне логично, на мой взгляд, вместо "сгущающуюся" употребить "сгущающиеся", но тогда звучит как-то натянуто.

Есть ли какое правило для таких случаев?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если определение относится только к одному из однородных членов - ясно, что оно ставится в форме единственного числа.

Если определение относится ко всем однородным членам, то по Розенталю ([§ 195. Определение при существительных – однородных членах](https://info.wikireading.ru/69463)):

1. Определение ставится в в форме единственного числа, если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например: российская печать, радио и телевидение; подъём нашей техники, науки и культуры.
2. Определение ставится в форме множественного числа, если по смыслу сочетания при единственном числе было бы неясно, связано ли определение с ближайшим существительным или со всем рядом однородных членов, например: способные ученик и ученица; построить каменные дом и гараж;

Если вы считаете, что сгущалась только тьма, используйте **единственное число**.

Если вы считаете, что сгущались и тьма, и страх, и зловоние, то используйте  **множественное число** (см. п. 2).

Comment: Понял, огромное спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

В вашем примере все верно. Причастие "сгущающуюся" согласовано в роде, числе и падеже с существительным "тьма".

Разогнать **что?** тьму - существительное женского рода, единственного числа, в винительном падеже.
Тьму **какую?** - сгущающуюся - причастие женского рода, единственного числа, в винительном падеже.

Comment: Почему только тьму? Разогнать (что?) тьму, страх и зловоние (однородные дополнения).

Comment: Да, конечно! Я вопрос не понял. Я думал, автора интересует только "падеж".

Answer (score 0):

Фраза, конечно, не айс, но сейчас речь не об этом... И не о правиле о согласовании числа. Сгущается только тьма. Как может сгущаться страх, а тем более зловоние? Только если это метафора.

Смысл такой:

> Мальчишки зарычали во все горло, пытаясь этим криком разогнать *тьму, которая сгущалась*, страх и зловоние.

Comment: Это отрывок из художественного текста. Меня конкретно интересует согласование числа для слова "сгущающуюся".
Зловоние вполне может сгущаться. Как и тучи. Как и сумерки.

Comment: Художественные тексты бывают разные. Но автор здесь явно имел в виду, что сгущается только тьма. "Сгущающаяся тьма" – это штамп, или постоянный эпитет, если угодно.

Comment: Автор этого текста - я. И я точно знаю, что я имел в виду.